# Accessing keys within Objects for use in a function

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have a nested object:

```
myObj = {
   id:'AA',
   child:{
      id:'BB',
      key1:'CC'
   },
   child2:{
      id:'DD',
      key1:'EE'
   },

};
```

I also have a function where I am currently doing this:

```
doSomething = function(id,childid,key){
  var str = id + childid + key;
  console.log(str);
};
doSomething(myObj.id,myObj.child.id,myObj.child.key1);
```

I would like to simplify to this:

```
doSomething2 = function(incObj){
  //myObj.child.key1;
  var str = incObj.id + ' ' + incObj.child.id + ' ' + incObj.child.key;
  //str = 'AA BB CC';
   console.log(str);

}
doSomething2(myObj.child.key1);
```

Is there a clean/simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you doing it:

```js
myObj = {
   id:'AA',
   child:{
      id:'BB',
      key1:'CC'
   },
   child2:{
      id:'DD',
      key1:'EE'
   },

};

doSomething2 = function(incObj){
  //myObj.child.key1;
  var str = incObj.id + ' ' + incObj.child.id + ' ' +incObj.child.key1;
  //str = 'AA BB CC';
   console.log(str);

}
doSomething2(myObj);
```

```js
myObj = {
   id:'AA',
   child:{
      id:'BB',
      key1:'CC'
   },
   child2:{
      id:'DD',
      key1:'EE'
   },

};

var config = {
  "child" : "child2",
  "key" :"key1"
}

doSomething2 = function(incObj, config){
  //myObj.child.key1;
  var str = incObj.id + ' ' + incObj[config.child].id + ' ' +incObj[config.child][config.key];
  //str = 'AA BB CC';
   console.log(str);

}
doSomething2(myObj,config);
```

Comment: This only works, if I am looking for key1,  what if I was looking for child1 or key2?

Comment: see updated code snippet. This can be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found the answer by yourself. You just have the pass the object and it's done.

Object:

```
myObj = {
   id:'AA',
   child:{
      id:'BB',
      key1:'CC'
   },
   child2:{
      id:'DD',
      key1:'EE'
   },

};
```

function:

```
doSomething2 = function(incObj){
  //myObj.child.key1;
  var str = incObj.id + ' ' + incObj.child.id + ' ' + incObj.child.key1;
   console.log(str);

}
doSomething2(myObj);
```